# Error to convert string to date in python

Tags: python

I want to convert string to date using `datetime.strptime` but it shows error `strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)`

I am trying to do this becausa i want to compare a date from twitter API to date from my database

```
tweetDate = datetime.strptime(tweetArrayData[1].split("l: ")[1],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

`tweetArrayData[1].split("l: ")[1]` refears to `23/03/2022 16:06:08` but i want to change format to `2022-03-23 16:06:08`

[image: error]

Comment: Your date is in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`, but your format string is for `YYYY/MM/DD`

Comment: Well, it *doesn't* match the format - you're trying to interpret 23 as the year, and 2022 as the day of the month.

Comment: The code in the screenshot isn't the same as the code you posted in the question text. Do you understand that the format string for `strptime()` is the format of the date in `tweetArrayData`, not the format that you want to display it?

Comment: This works `datetime.strptime("23/03/2022 16:06:08", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`.